# Необычный ListView с панелью при клике, возможно?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio

Приветствую.

Возможно ли сделать такой ListView, как на картинке? Картинка, естественно, фотошопная. )) Но суть от этого не меняется. При клике на item в списке ListView показать панель под итемом, по которому кликнули (не закрывая панелью элементы, а сместить их под панель).
Если такое возможно, то расскажите, как осуществить, желательно с практикой. )

[image: http://s55.radikal.ru/i149/1411/54/fc0c2bdfcf9d.png]

**Обновление**

> Да, важный вопрос: вы знакомы с MVVM?

Нет, но осваиваю по тихонько, мое путешествие в C# началось с консоли до WinForm, сейчас с wpf начал осваивать. Вы не могли бы полностью проект скинуть, я очень сложно понимаю взаимодействие с кодом и wpf элементарные вещи смогу сделать, но когда дело доходит до модификации компонент и прочее, то тут уже сложности.

Comment: Можно. По идее, вам нужно иметь два темлейта: один для свёрнутого, один для развёрнутого состояния элемента. Ну и переключать их по `IsSelected`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вот вам пример:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:ItemVM}">
            <Grid>
                <!-- шаблон для обычного состояния -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding BasicInfo}" Name="BasicInfoPart"/>
                <!-- шаблон для развёрнутого состояния -->
                <StackPanel Visibility="Collapsed" Name="AdvancedInfoPart">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BasicInfo}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AdvancedInfo}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                           AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="BasicInfoPart"
                            Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="AdvancedInfoPart"
                            Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

У меня работает:

[image: скриншот]

**Обновление**

Смотрите. У вас есть VM-тип, правильно? У меня он называется `ItemVM`, у вас как-то по-другому. Для того, чтобы мне сослаться на `ItemVM`, я должен указать, в каком namespace'е он находится. Для этого делается так:

```
<Window x:Class="ExpandableListView.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:ExpandableListView"
    Title="..." Height="350" Width="525">
```

Таким образом `l` определяется как namespace `ExpandableListView` в текущем assembly. (Вот полный код: http://pastebin.com/LM0a0B0a.) у вас, понятно, другой namespace, да и `ItemVM` наверное называется по-другому.

Да, важный вопрос: вы знакомы с MVVM?

Comment: Пишет <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:ItemVM}"> l не определен. Я с wpf мало работал, как определить этот класс? И ваш пример будет работать если добавить колонки?

Comment: @updat: Не нашёл, куда выложить архив, запаковал в файл (запустите для распаковки): http://pastebin.com/dfBzrLqb

Comment: Ну вы и заморочились, спасибо! Вот только ваш пример с колонками не работает. То есть если добавить колонку, то панель уже не отображается. http://s013.radikal.ru/i324/1411/71/5dda6dde237f.png

Comment: @updat: А как именно вы добавили колонки?

---
PS: У вас должен подойти к концу лимит комментариев, удаляйте старые.

Comment: Вот так.


       <ListView.View >
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Test" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GeneralInfo}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>


У меня есть рабочий пример с такой панелью и с колонками, но в нем нельзя менять или задавать индивидуальную для каждой колонки ширину.

Comment: Ну. А зачем вы пользуетесь `DisplayMemberBinding`? Делайте так: http://pastebin.com/6WuWJfWh

Comment: Вы меня не поняли!!! Мне нужен <ListView> с колонками, и с панелью при клике на строку, панель и элементы на панели не должны зависть от размера колонок и вообще от колонок, панель должна быть независимая!